# NancyFX calls action without request from browser

Tags: asp.net, nancy

There is smth strange in my NanceFX app.
I've created an "action" for GET request with a name "Load".
Now I just start my application and begin type a url for "load" action and it calls without pressing enter! How is it possible?

Comment: Also there is an empty page for this action. So it isn't a javascript. I thinks that could be a browser. I'm using chrome. Somebody know anything about such feature?

Comment: Nancy does not have actions...

Comment: I am not sure what " without зкуыыштп enter" means, but if you mean it's requesting something from Nancy then it might be the favicon, or if you mean you hit a breakpoint inside your module constructor that'll be the initial route scanning to build the route table.

Comment: Sorry about "зкуыыштп" it means "pressing" :) And no it isn't initial route scanning because request handler executes after application completely started.

Comment: Are you using chrome? Chrome does speculative requests sometimes in order have already fetches content when the user hits enter.

Comment: Christian Horsdal, yeap as I've wrote earlier I'm using chrome. Could you please tell me where I can find more information about this chrome speculative requests? Thanks.